# Remove region within HTML

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I want to remove a self imposed region within HTML. I've worked out the correct regex, which I've proved in [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm), and the correct section is highlighted.

[image: Expresso]

I ran this in multiline mode, and have set prepended this setting to the PowerShell regex string

```
Get-ChildItem (Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName -Recurse -Filter *.html |
Foreach-Object {
    Write-Host "Checking "$_.FullName
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
    $content = $content -replace "(?m)(^.*\#region REMOVE.*)[.|\n|\W|\w]*(^.*\#endregion REMOVE.*)",""
    Set-Content $content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

Sadly the region is not removed, although the file has been touched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Get-Content documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content):

> The Get-Content cmdlet gets the content of the item at the location
>   specified by the path, such as the text in a file. It reads the
>   content one line at a time and returns a collection of objects, each
>   of which represents a line of content.

So your regex is executing on an array, not a string of the file contents. Change to this:

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName);
```

And it will work.

Comment: Works like a treat! Thanks for that.